# How to find get the Desktop address for a user on Windows?

Tags: arrays, c, file, char

I was trying to write a C code to create a file on the Desktop. I used getenv() to get the username for the address, but it is printing some weird symbols.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char raw[] = "C://Users/%/Desktop/xyz.txt";
    char loc[strlen(raw)+strlen(getenv("USERNAME"))-1] = "";
    char *env = ""; 
    strcpy(env ,getenv("USERNAME"));

    for (int i = -1; i < sizeof(raw); ++i){
        if (raw[i]!='%'){
            strcpy(loc, raw[i]);
        }
        else if (raw[i]=='%'){
            strcpy(loc, env);
        }
    }

    printf(loc);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I wrote(please forgive the variable names). And This is what I got:
`Évs♦↨║╨↕@`

I am using GCC.

P.S. I am new to the language, so sorry if it's a silly question.

Edit - I forgot to mention that I wanted to get a variable with the address, so I could use it for other things.

Comment: `char *env; strcpy(env...)` is writing to an dangling pointer. Assign `loc` to point to valid memory first (one way to do this is by allocating it with `malloc`)

Comment: Not only is `env` not pointing at anything, so undefined behaviour to use - but also, you can't allocate `loc` like that, because `sizeof(char*)` gives the size of the pointer, not the size of the string it points to. Get the result of `getenv()`, get its `strlen`, allocate that+1 or greater characters, and then `strcpy()` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At:

```
    strcpy(env ,getenv("USERNAME"));
```

the pointer `env` is unitialised.  It needs to reference specifically allocated memory to which `strcpy()` can copy the string.

Other then that you have in any case somewhat over-complicated the solution.  Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char loc[MAX_PATH + 1] ;
    sprintf( loc, "C:\\Users\\%s\\Desktop\\xyz.txt",  getenv("USERNAME") ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", loc);

    return 0;
}
```

However it is a flawed assumption. My desktop folder for example is on `D:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop` - a user can move their special folders to any location they wish (as I have). Moreover different versions of Windows have in any case placed it various other *default* locations.  For example on XP `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%`.

You should ask the OS where its OS special folders are.  For example using [SHGetFolderPathA()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    char loc[MAX_PATH + 1] ;
    SHGetFolderPathA( NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 0, loc) ; 
    printf( "%s\n", loc);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, check the Qt sources for these kinds of things. At least that's what I do when looking for this type of stuff.

You can find the way they do it [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/7ee682a1ddc259225618b57ff00f4c36ff5e724c/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths_win.cpp#L190). Mind you, it's written in C++, but the OS details usually boil down to plain C at some point, because that's the low-level API provided by the operating system (yes, even on Mac, even though that takes some figuring out to get everything right).

Basically, they call [`shGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) from Shell32.dll with the GUID [`FOLDERID_Desktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid).

Note that what you're doing is fine in a sense, but relying on environment variables is somewhat dangerous, and they don't cater for a lot of things you might want to get.

Comment: The idea behind what they're doing might be "fine in a sense" (I don't know either way), but the _way they're trying to do it_ is very wrong, as they didn't understand how to allocate strings at all.

Comment: @underscore_d : The context of rubenvb's statement was clearly with respect to the idea of constructing the path from the environment variable.  Perhaps _"what you're _trying_ to do..._" .  It is true that this answer does not address the flaw in the code in question,  but rather addresses the problem the code attempts to solve.  It is an XY problem, and as such do you fix the problem, or fix the solution?

Comment: I answered the question as stated: "How to find get the Desktop address for a user on Windows?" and took a brief look at the code. I'm not going to try to debug fundamentally broken code that uses a sub-optimal approach if the actual question is about something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This one is specific to windows. `USERPROFILE` environment variable should get the path for user home in which case desktop path can be calculated as below.

```
char desktop_path[MAX_PATH + 1] ;
sprintf( desktop_path, "%s\\Desktop", getenv("USERPROFILE") ) ;

char filepath[MAX_PATH + 1] ;
sprintf( filepath, "%s\\%s", desktop_path, "whateverfile.txt" ) ;
```